# spawn child process inside for loop

Tags: python, node.js

Below is the complete working code, only place where i have commented with `\\not working` is where i m facing issue.

this is general query for using spawn process in my nodejs script, in which i am creating and executing spawn process inside a forloop of the nodejs script. That forloop has list of element which on each loop send the element to python script which using the element perform some operation and return result.

**What i m doing is that i m saving the result in javascript array inside the nodejs script (But this is not executing).** while earlier i was able to display the returned results.

I want to create spawn process for each element and then save that in javascript array instead of displaying the return values from the python script.

Nodejs code for reference, which has for loop, see `output_array = []` i want to save the spawn result of each element of the for loop in this output array.

```
const express = require("express"),
  app = express();

var server = http.createServer(app);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
// Creates a server which runs on port 3000 and 
// can be accessed through localhost:3000 
app.listen(port, () => { 
    console.log(`server running on port at ${port}`); 
})

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'index.html'));
});

app.post('/getscorelist', getscorelist);

function getscorelist(req, res){

    csvData = req.files.csvfile.data.toString('utf8');
    csvData = csvData.split(/\r\n/)
    output_array = []

    for (var i=1;i<csvData.length;i++){

        console.log(csvData[i])

        // Send request to python script
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

        var process = spawn('python', ["-u", "./test.py", csvData[i].trim()])
    
        process.stdout.on('data', function(data){

            // Not working
            res.send("<p>"+data.toString()+"</p>")

        });

    }
}
```

and console output of the above code is as attached where you can see that 5 same title is printed which i think is related to first number of the csv file only. It should be different string as the number are different.

[image]

HTML code which send the csv file data to the nodejs script. Also i was earlier made code for ajax in this html file to send this request to nodejs api and get the result in csv file and generate link which will then allow the user to download the results. for this i have made a div tag `<div id="linkforoutput"></div>`

```
<div class="multidiv">
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/getscorelist">
                <p for="">Please upload csv file (having list of patent numbers):
                <br>
                <input type="file" style="cursor: pointer;" name="csvfile" id="csvfile" accept=".csv"></p><br><br>
                <button type="submit" id="submit_button" style="cursor: pointer;">Submit</button><br><br>         
            </form>
            <div id="linkforoutput"></div>
        </div>
```

Below is the csv file or elements of for loop in the nodejs script

```
patent
9015616
9015617
9015618
9015699
7843093
```

Lets this `mainfile.py` is the python file which perform as follow as

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

patent_number = sys.argv[1]
patent_number = patent_number.strip()

ur = "https://patents.google.com/patent/US"+str(patent_number)

ur = "https://patents.google.com/patent/US9015699"
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36',
})
content = requests.get(ur, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text,'html.parser')
strin = soup.title.get_text().split("-")[1]

strin = strin.strip()

print(strin)
```

**what i m trying is as below**, i m able to get the console output of  `console.log(csvData[i])` but not able to get the output of `console.log(data.toString())`

```
app.post('/getscorelist', getscorelist);

function getscorelist(req, res){

    csvData = req.files.csvfile.data.toString('utf8');
    csvData = csvData.split(/\r\n/)
    output_array = []

    for (var i=1;i<csvData.length;i = i+1){


        console.log(csvData[i])

        // Send request to python script
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

        var process = spawn('python', ["-u", "./test.py", csvData[i].trim()])
    
        process.stdout.on('data', function(data){

            console.log(data.toString())
    
        // data_csv_string = data.toString()
        // var strin = data_csv_string.trim()
        // strin = strin.replace(/(\r)/gm, "");
        // output_array.push(strin)
        // res.send(200)

        });

        
    }
}
```

Comment: I m shocked that i m very near to solution but not getting the right suggestion in this SO

Comment: @kabanus please see i have updated code

Answer (score 0):

I think a cleaner approach to solving this problem would be to use a REQUEST-RESPONSE / RPC pattern provided by by the likes of ZeroMQ, which you can use to communicate your express.js server with the python-based beautifulsoup service. The result, in my opinion, would be a lot more modular and reusable. The management of python virtualenv would remain separate. Otherwise, it would be difficult to manage and trigger the correct interpreter and associated environment variables.

Here are a few links:

- https://zeromq.org/languages/nodejs/
- https://zeromq.org/languages/python/

For example, here is the code snippet for an RPC client in node.js from the official guide for ZeroMQ:

```
// Hello World client
// Connects REQ socket to tcp://localhost:5555
// Sends "Hello" to server.

var zmq = require('zeromq');

// socket to talk to server
console.log("Connecting to hello world server...");
var requester = zmq.socket('req');

var x = 0;
requester.on("message", function(reply) {
  console.log("Received reply", x, ": [", reply.toString(), ']');
  x += 1;
  if (x === 10) {
    requester.close();
    process.exit(0);
  }
});

requester.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log("Sending request", i, '...');
  requester.send("Hello");
}

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  requester.close();
});
```

And here is the corresponding server in python:

```
#
#   Hello World server in Python
#   Binds REP socket to tcp://*:5555
#   Expects b"Hello" from client, replies with b"World"
#

import time
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

while True:
    #  Wait for next request from client
    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received request: %s" % message)

    #  Do some 'work'
    time.sleep(1)

    #  Send reply back to client
    socket.send(b"World")
```

I think the above examples can be modified to suit the current problem as well.

Comment: Hi, i didn't get it

Comment: Hi, can you help me in this

Comment: Hello @Nickjones, I have posted an update to my earlier answer.